# get the value from one master to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

iam using a dropdownlist in one master page. i want to get the dropdownlist value in session and i want to use it in another master page.

how to do this.

Comment: Assuming you're using ASP.NET ... can you tell us the version of framework you're using?

Comment: can you give a little more information about the scene? 2 masterpages living totally sperated from eachother? if so I think I can answer this one

Answer (score 0):

To put the selected value in the session, you can do something like this:

```
protected void ddlMyDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["MySelectedValue"] = ddlMyDropDown.SelectedValue;
}
```

This stores the selected value in the Session with the key "MySelectedValue".

When you want to read it back, you can do this:

```
string myValue = Session["MySelectedValue"]
```

It might be an idea to wrap up your access to the session in a class so it's all strongly-typed, and allows for you to add validation or other logic:

```
// Strongly-typed access to session data
public class MySessionData
{
    // Gets the username of the current logged in user if logged in, otherwise null.
    public string MyUsername
    {
        get { return Session["MyUsername"]; }
        set { Session["MyUsername"] = value; }
    }
}
```